# Смёрджить ветки заменой папки

Tags: git, git-merge

Нужно смёрджить ветки, причём корректным результатом будет полностью заменить одну из папок и совсем не трогать другие.

Попытался сделать так:

1. Удалить папку, которую нужно заменить.
2. Выполнить слияние командой

   ```
   git merge features/branch-name -s theirs -- folder-name
   ```

Но при этом возникает ошибка, что стратегия не найдена:

> Could not find merge strategy 'theirs'.
>   Available strategies are: octopus ours recursive resolve subtree.

Как же заменить папку правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Намудрил (вот прям чую, что можно проще), но вроде получилось:

1. Выполнить merge оставив все свои файлы

   ```
   git merge features/branch-name -s ours
   ```
2. Удалить папку, которую нужно заменить
3. Выкачать папку из интересующей ветки

   ```
   git checkout features/branch-name -- folder-name
   ```
4. Добавить все интересующие файлы и закоммитить с изменением предыдущего коммита

   ```
   git add *
   git commit --amend
   ```

Comment: А если мы удалили папку, а потом скачали папку - мы ведь потеряем свои изменения, которые делали в этой папке?

Comment: @YozhEzhi, предполагалось, что незакоммиченных изменений в ветках нет. И требовалось именно полностью заменить её версией из другой ветки. А так-то да - всё, что было в папке теряется (хотя закоммиченное остаётся в истории гита).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такой вариант ([источник](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/)).
Находясь на ветке, в которую нужно вмерджить - выполняем команду:

```
git checkout some_branch img/avatar.svg js/main.js styles/main.scss
```

Файлы должны скопироваться и поместиться в stage.

Если файлов в папке много - способ не удобен, согласен.
Но я подозреваю, что можно попробовать указать путь а-ля `folder_name/**/*`

Comment: Это не merge. В моём ответе то же самое на третьем шаге. Я хотел, чтобы в истории показывалось, что ветка вмёрджена, а это действие даёт только файлы из той ветки, но ветка остаётся несвязанной.

Comment: Кстати, это да...