# Git: выполнить pull поверх прежней версии избежав вынужденного merge нового и старого кода

Tags: git

Не получается произвести Push на удалённый репозиторий Bitbusket. Ошибка:

```
Git remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch
```

В большинстве предложенных решений говорится, что надо выполнить `Pull`, а потом уже `Push`. Но, как я и ожидал, `Pull` привёл к наложению старого состояния проекта, который хранится на удалённом репозитории, на новый (то есть добавился ненужный старый код, а где-то и вовсе код продублировался). В результате у меня чуть не полетел весь проект (еле-еле откатил, чуть не потеряв 6 часов работы ...).

Мне больше не нужно старое состояние проекта на удалённом репозитории, потому я не хочу его merge с новым, мне нужно просто обновить удалённый репозиторий, причём ветвь `master`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Этой веткой кто-то кроме вас пользуется?

Comment: @D-side, нет, пока не никто.

Comment: старый master вам нужен?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman: если Вы о том master, который сейчас находится в удалённом репозитории, то нет.

Comment: тогда воспользуйтесь ответом Nick `git push -f origin master`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/639553/178988 - думаю, тоже может подойти

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Только если репозиторий лично ваш и никто другой им не пользуется, можно осущестить «переписывание истории» — это когда вы как бы «удаляете коммиты» из ветки.

#### Теория

Так выглядит обычная ситуация перед пушем. У вас в `master` есть новые коммиты, на сервере в `origin/master` их ещё нет:

```
A – B – C    origin/master
         \
          D  master
```

В результате `git push origin master` будет:

```
A – B – C — D   master, origin/master
```

---

Вот что происходит у вас:

```
A – B – C    origin/master
     \
       D     master
```

Гит не позволяет просто так взять и запушить `master` в `origin/master`, потому что коммит `C` потеряется. Это и называется **«переписыванием истории»**. Его можно осуществить принудительно, с ключом `--force` или `-f`. **Это опасная команда, нельзя ей пользоваться в общем репозитории**, [читайте о подробностях и последствиях, включая «бьют по лицу».](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429512/181472)

После `git push --force origin master`:

```
A – B – D    master, origin/master
     \
       C     (потерян)
```

#### Практика:

1. Возможно ветка `master` защищена на удаленном репозитории — нельзя переписывать её историю. В настройках удаленного репозитория (то есть на bitbucket) снимите защиту ветки или выдайте себе права на переписывание. ([Bitbucket – branch permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-permissions-385912271.html))
2. Выполните `git push -f origin master`.
3. Верните защиту ветки.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробное объяснение! От души написанный ответ, что сказать...

Comment: @GurebuBokofu пожалуйста. Ещё вот это вам может пригодиться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472

Comment: Кто сказал, что `git push -f` нельзя использовать в общем репозитории? Правильнее написать *не рекомендуется* И дописать *вы должны понимать, что вы делаете*. (Да, очевидно, что под *общим репозиторием* могут пониматься несколько разные вещи)

Comment: @0andriy все время забываю упомянуть, что речь только о стабильных ветках, а фичеветки — в зависимости от командных договоренностей. Завтра подумаю, как переформулировать.

Comment: @0andriy тут ведь какое дело: если писать "не рекомендуется и вы должны понимать", то человек может подумать, что понимает, хотя на самом деле не понимает. Поэтому перестраховываюсь. Тех, кто действительно всё понимает, такая инструкция не остановит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и это тоже не совсем корректно. Очень много здесь зависит как от проекта, так и от процесса. У нас в конторе есть репозиторий, которым пользуются, наверное, 100+ человек, на регулярной основе там делается rebase. Соответственно force push. Потому что основной репозиторий, который можно назвать *целевым*, не у нас, но он (целевой репозиторий) действительно работает по принципу: "замержили регрессию, тогда мержим реверт или фикс". (Это комментарий на ваш предыдущий)

Comment: @0andriy форспуши наверняка в фичеветках делаются перед мержем в мастер, так?

Comment: Да, но и в мастер тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Удали удаленную ветку командой git push origin  :master (название удаленки напиши свое) и залей туда свои данные командой git push -u origin master

Comment: Благодарю Вас за овет! К сожалению, не получилось выполнить `git push origin https://bitbucket.org/ExampleName/example.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`. Пишет `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in https://bitbucket.org/ExampleName/example.git`.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, если Вы про мой удалённый репозиторий, то там нет ничего ценного.

Comment: Вы ставили ключ -u ?